# validate_on_submit() fails when RadioButton choices are dynamically generated

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am creating quiz-like web application for learning languages using Flask, Jinja, WTForms, SqlAlchemy etc. Once an user completes such a language course by successfully going through all levels stored in JSON file I want the app offer him a practice mode, where the user will answer randomly selected levels.

When I run the app, I can see radio buttons generated with values from random level as I want, but when I choose any answer and submit it, **form.validate_on_submit() returns False** and form.errors returns **{'practiceform': [u'Not a valid choice']}**. When I hard-code value to currentLevel variable, it works properly.

**views.py**

```
@user_blueprint.route('/courses/<course>/quiz/practice',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def practice(course):
    courseClass = class_for_name("project.models", course.capitalize())
    courses = courseClass.query.filter_by(email=current_user.email).first()
    maxLevel = courseClass.query.filter_by(email=current_user.email).first().get_maxLevel()
    currentLevel = randint(0, maxLevel-1) # If this value is hard-coded or fetched from db, it works correctly

    dic = generateQuestion(course, currentLevel)
    display = dic["display"]
    correct = dic["correct"]
    options = dic["options"]

    form = PracticeForm(request.form)
    form.practiceform.choices = [(option, option) for option in options]


    if form.validate_on_submit():
        practiceForm = form.practiceform.data

        if ((practiceForm == correct) and courses):
            # Do something
            flash("Nice job", 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('user.practice', course=course))

        else:
            # Do something else
            flash("Wrong answer", 'danger')
            return redirect(url_for('user.practice', course=course))

    return render_template('courses/practice.html', form=form, display=display)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PracticeForm(Form):

    practiceform = RadioField('practice')
```

**practice.html**

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form action='' method='POST' role='form'>
    <p>
        <!-- Tried put form.csrf, form.csrf_token, form.hidden_tag() here -->
        {{ form.practiceform() }}
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

So what am I missing there? What makes difference between lets say hardcoded level 25, which works properly or if the number 25 is randomly generated within randint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that randint() caused the problem because the practice(course) method was called on both GET and POST actions which led to having two different integers -> two different forms most of the time. So I refactored the code. kept the practice(course) method for GET action and created a new method which handles POST action and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `option` is a `int`, bug WTForms get a `str` from `request.form`.

When data comes back from requests it is treated as a `string` by WTForms unless you specify a type explicitly with the `coerce` kwarg of the `wtforms.fields.*Field` constructor:

```
practiceform = RadioField('practice', coerce=int)
```